# Where to get @types for single lodash package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, lodash

I need one function from lodash - assignin. I installed `lodash.assignin` and imported it in my project:

```
import assignIn = require('lodash.assignin');
```

But after compilation there is an error: "error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash.assignin'".

I understand that I need typings for `lodash.assignin` package, but unfortunately there is only `lodash/assignin` type in `@types/lodash`.

I don't want install whole lodash package for just one of its function, so does lodash have typings for their single packages?

Comment: Its not `lodash.assignin` but `lodash.assign`

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran sorry, what do you mean? https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.assignin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That package (lodash.assignin) is not available, please check list of available lodash packages here https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/lodash-modularized

For example if I want to use the `first` method I need to install `npm i --save lodash.first`
Then I use the method like this `const first = require('lodash.first');`

Comment: What do you mean it's not available? It's the same as other packages https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/4.2.0-npm-packages

Comment: Anyway, syntax `const assignIn = require('lodash.assignin')` works well for me, despite it is mostly node-like variant.

Comment: You are right, it is available. I think you are not installing the package correctly since I have tested locally and it works. Did you do `npm i --save lodash.assignin` ?

Comment: You cannot use `import` in node.js yet

Comment: I'm saying that using `require` is node style to import modules. In typescript it's preferred to use word `import`.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this for a different package with the following:

**src/types/lodash.groupby.d.ts:**

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash'

export default groupBy
```

`yarn add -D '@types/lodash@^4.6.0'`

Then import with:

```
import groupBy from 'lodash.groupby'
```

This is using TypeScript 2.9.